# sk_buff / net_device: Minimum packet size?

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

I understand that a MTU is defined in `struct net_device`, and (if I'm correct) that MTU is defined on a per-device basis.

Is there a way to get a *minimum* packet size?  I know there are clear cut definitions for e.g. IPv4, but in this case it would depend on the network interface, right?

Also, some drivers allocate an `skb` before receiving a packet.  In this case, if the driver implements `change_mtu`, what happens to the `skb` that has already been allocated? Does it simply get destroyed and then the driver would allocate a new skb to reflect the changed MTU?

Comment: **`sk_buff`** is a **descriptor of packet**, **not packet's data memory** itself. So it doesn't directly depend on the MTU, size of payload and so on (but sometimes there can be "paged skb"). Btw what do you mean by "packet size"? Is it TCP/UDP packet or IP datagram or whatever?

Comment: @budoattack I am not sure, I'm actually looking at ``__netdev_alloc_skb`` which takes ``struct net_device`` and an arbitrary length as an argument, the length being the length of the packet, so I thought the type of payload would vary depending on what interface ``net_device`` is using.